# Hibernate 4 Error on sessionFactory creation

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-4.x

During upgrading to Hibernate 4 from its 3.v, I run into this problem occurred at the TC starting up.

```
... Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:790)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processFkSecondPassInOrder(Configuration.java:1415)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1355)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1724)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1775)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:184)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:314)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 55 more
```

And the sessionFactory in my configuration file is done as the following:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>shippingCharge.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.abc.myapp.account.domain.ProfileInfo</value>
            <value>com.abc.myapp.account.domain.Profile</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${hibernate.generate_statistics}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <!--  removed for hibernate 4. any replacement?
    <property name="eventListeners">
        <map>
            <entry key="merge">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.IdTransferringMergeEventListener" />
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
    -->
</bean>
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: It may be foreign-key related. Maybe you could find some pointers here  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302993/hibernate-throwing-nullpointerexception-processfksecondpassinorder

Comment: add an answer if you find a solution based on @nico_ekito's advice.

Comment: Thanks for your information. In fact, I already read the post. I, however, don't think it is the same situation. This error occurs under a situation which my code hasn't been changed but Hibernate version from 3.6.8 to 4.1.0. I don't know whether the 4 version come with some special requirements on foreign key annotation configuration over the 3.6.8 version or not.

Comment: Please show your hbm file and your 2 domain classes.

Comment: The total number of domain classes are 25 which are mapped with annotations. It is not reality to show all domain classes here. The hbm file is something like the following:

Comment: <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
                                   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="..." default-access="field">

    <class name="Charge" table="charge">
        <id name="id" type="int" column="item_fk"/>
        <many-to-one name="shop" column="shop_fk" class="..." not-null="true"/>        
     <component name="singleCharge" class="Charge">
...      
     </component>
     <component name="charge" class="Charge">
...     
     </component>
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>

Comment: I am aware the DTD is the 3 version, but not 4. I, however, haven't seen using 4 in the dtd.

Answer (score 2):

Please replace `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder` instead of `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean`. This might help.

Comment: Could you also include a reference link for more reading? Why does this solve the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

it's maybe a spring issue.
you can change 
`<property name="annotatedClasses">`
 to
 `<property name="packagesToScan"` 
and try it again

Answer (score 0):

this may be a stale jar file issue, i ran with the same error
then in my log file i found `Could not obtain connection metadata : DatabaseMetaData information is not known for server DB2/LINUXX8664SQL09010 by this version of JDBC driver`
then i replaced my this project db2 jar files with one running project jars and it starts running smoothly

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue in my code. Then i tried updating the recent versions of DB2 jars into my server and the code started working. Try to update your DB2 jar.