# How to resolve Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource in Hibernate4

Tags: java, spring, session, tomcat, spring-mvc

I am using Hibernate4 in my application for multitenancy implementation while building application war i got following error in my catalina of tomcat.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: 
protected org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.boxco.blip.dao.BaseDao.sessionFactory; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error    creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-persistence.xml]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Here is my application -persistance.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="...">

<context:annotation-config />
<tx:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.boxco.blip">
</context:component-scan>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>jdbc/blip</value>
    </property>
    <property name="resourceRef">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
</bean>


<!-- Hibernate Session Factory  -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
    <value>com.boxco.blip.model.Address</value> 
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">          
         <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
            <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false" />
            <entry key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="0" />
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="after_transaction" />
            <entry key="hibernate.multiTenancy" value="SCHEMA" />
            <entry key="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver" value-ref="multiTenantIdentifierResolver1" />
            <entry key="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider" value-ref="multiTenantConnectionProvider1" />      
      </map>
    </property>
</bean>

 <bean id="multiTenantConnectionProvider1" class="com.boxco.blip.web.util.SchemaMultiTenantConnectionProviderBlip">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
  </bean>
 <bean id="multiTenantIdentifierResolver1" class="com.boxco.blip.web.util.SchemaCurrentTenantIdentifierResolverBlip" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

MY AddressDao.java File

```
package com.boxco.blip.dao;

import com.boxco.blip.model.Address;

public interface AddressDao {
   public Address getAddressByAddressId(int addressId);
 }
```

My AddressDaoImpl.java file

```
package com.boxco.blip.dao;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.boxco.blip.model.Address;
@Component
@Repository(value = "addressDao")

public class AddressDaoImpl extends BaseDao implements AddressDao {
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AddressDaoImpl.class);

    @Override
 public Address getAddressByAddressId(int addressId) {
    logger.info("Entering getAddressByAddressId()........");
    Address address = null;
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Address.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("addressId", addressId));
    criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    address = (Address)criteria.uniqueResult();
    logger.info("Exiting getAddressByAddressId()..........");
    return address;
}
```

}

My Base Dao file where i init sessionFactory object:

```
package com.boxco.blip.dao;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;

public abstract class BaseDao 
 {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("sessionFactory")
protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

protected void init(SessionFactory factory) {
    try {
        setSessionFactory(factory);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

public Session getSession() throws HibernateException {
    // return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    return sessionFactory.withOptions().tenantIdentifier("BLIP1314ERP")
            .openSession();
}

     //some more methods
  }
```

My Dispatcher-servlet.xml file where   is added

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="...">

<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.boxco">
    <!-- <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression="com.boxco.blip.dao.*" /> -->
</context:component-scan>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver">
    <property name="basenames" value="views"/>

<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <value>messages,error_codes</value>
    </property>
</bean> 

<bean id="validatorFactory"
      class="org.springmodules.validation.commons.DefaultValidatorFactory">
    <property name="validationConfigLocations">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/validator-rules.xml</value>
            <value>/WEB-INF/validator.xml</value>
            <value>/WEB-INF/validatorFas.xml</value>
            <value>/WEB-INF/validatorFas-rules.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="validator" class="org.springmodules.validation.commons.DefaultBeanValidator">
    <property name="validatorFactory" ref="validatorFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Error is in my `SessionFactory` initialization but why it is not getting init is my problem..?
(I am handling this error first time)..

Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9508408/1686330

Comment: @Dirk Lachowski I already reffer that link and added org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean & <property name="packagesToScan"> to my .xml file

Comment: Could you show us the full stack trace for the NullPointerException?

Comment: also add package names of `BaseDao`, `AddressDao` and `AddressDaoImpl` classes.

Comment: and if you have `<context:component-scan ...>` in any other context file except `application-persistance.xml` add that too to your question

Comment: @AditiK you have added imports but forgot to add package names..

Comment: @Rembo i have edited my files plz check once

Comment: @AditiK if you use `username` and `password` in `hibernate.cfg.xml` remove those lines, will solve problem.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be your solution, in any case the @component annotation over @repository is useless. Either you insert @repository (better for exception translation) or @component.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by replacing my JAR files from 4.3.4 to 4.1.7 (downgraded my jar) hibernate version ,I dont know why its not working with latest versions of Hibernate