# Spring 4 - Hibernate 5 - Error Creating LocalSessionFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Has been struggling for 1 night, yesterday everything is okay. I think I messed up somewhere.

Has anyone have clue where is the issue? below log is not helping me to find the culprit.

Please let me know what do you want me to share here.

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with
        name 'agentPointDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'init' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating
        bean with name 'localSessionFactoryBean' defined in xxx.sma.engine.ConfigurationRepository: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointer
        Exception
        Mar 16, 2017 7:16:56 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
        SEVERE: Context initialization failed
        org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'agentPointDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'init' parameter 0; n
        ested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'localSessionFactoryBean' defined in xxx.sma.engine.Configura
        tionRepository: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:671)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:754)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4937)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'localSessionFactoryBean' defined in xxx.sma.engine.ConfigurationRepo
        sitory: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1131)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1059)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:663)
        ... 24 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1674)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1583)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:511)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:495)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579)
        ... 34 more

        Mar 16, 2017 7:16:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
        SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'agentPointDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'init' parameter 0; n
        ested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'localSessionFactoryBean' defined in xxx.sma.engine.Configura
        tionRepository: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:671)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:754)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4937)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'localSessionFactoryBean' defined in xxx.sma.engine.ConfigurationRepo
        sitory: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1131)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1059)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:663)
        ... 24 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1674)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1583)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:511)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:495)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579)
        ... 34 more

        Mar 16, 2017 7:16:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
        SEVERE: Error listenerStart
```

Here some of my code:

ConfigurationRepository.java

```
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({"xxx.sma.engine"})
public class ConfigurationRepository {

    //development
    public final static String DB_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@xx.xxx.xx.x:1521:orcl";
    public final static String DB_USERNAME = "XXX";
    public final static String DB_PASSWORD = "xxx";
    public final static Integer DB_MAX_POOL = 2;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        localSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        localSessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(properties());
        localSessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"xxx.sma.engine.model"});
        return localSessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        hibernateTransactionManager.setSessionFactory(localSessionFactoryBean().getObject());
        return hibernateTransactionManager;
    }

    private DataSource dataSource() {
        HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource();
        hikariDataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(DB_MAX_POOL);
        hikariDataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        hikariDataSource.setJdbcUrl(DB_URL);
        hikariDataSource.setUsername(DB_USERNAME);
        hikariDataSource.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);
        return hikariDataSource;
    }

    private Properties properties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
        return properties;
    }

}
```

AgentPointDao.java

```
import com.genevacons.h3i.sma.engine.model.AgentPoint;
public interface AgentPointDao extends HibernateDao {
    AgentPoint getByUserId(Integer userId);
}
```

AgentPointDaoImpl.java

```
import com.genevacons.h3i.sma.engine.dao.AgentPointDao;
import com.genevacons.h3i.sma.engine.dao.BgDao;
import com.genevacons.h3i.sma.engine.model.AgentPoint;
import com.genevacons.h3i.sma.engine.model.Bg;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import java.util.List;

@Repository("agentPointDao")
public class AgentPointDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoImpl<AgentPoint> implements AgentPointDao {
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public AgentPointDaoImpl() {
        super(AgentPoint.class);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void init(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
    public AgentPoint getByUserId(Integer userId) {
        List<AgentPoint> agentPointList = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from AgentPoint where user.userId = :userId", AgentPoint.class)
                .setParameter("userId", userId)
                .getResultList();
        return agentPointList.isEmpty() ? null : agentPointList.get(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Some code might help.

Comment: @CollinD some code added, please share your though, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From stacktrace you can see that it's probably related to configuration (namely, FK - foreign key - not found):

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1674)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1583)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:511)
```

So, double check you entities configuration do not contain some dangling foreign keys / make sure your package scan includes all the entities.

Here are some similar problems from stackoverflow: [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448116/how-i-can-find-the-exact-error), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302993/hibernate-throwing-nullpointerexception-processfksecondpassinorder)

Comment: You need to dig into source code for that, for instance https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/boot/internal/InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java, but I can't say the exact problem without debugging unfortunately

Comment: can't believe thrown exception not helping me, thanks for your help @borowis. Those FK issue I've fix it. It's working now.